# iOS 4.3 image for Verizon iPhone 4

Tags: ios, iphone, ios4

I'm learning iPhone app development.

For backward compatibility testing purposes I'm keeping an old iPhone on iOS 4. It's on iOS 4.2, but a lot of reasons (especially Corona) are pushing me to bring it up just a little, to iOS 4.3. It's a Verizon iPhone 4. Looking on iClarified, I can't find a version of iOS 4.3 that will install to my phone. Like it's missing or something.

Anybody out there understand this list, to know whether it's missing or what version I should be downloading?

Comment: If you're only just learning iOS, do yourself a favour and only bother with the latest version.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no 4.3 for iPhone 4 CDMA.